# PayPal shipping rates for non US accounts

Tags: paypal

I have and Australian PayPal account that i'm using to process payments on my site through the Basic Website Payment buttons. It seem that shipping regions is only available for US accounts. Is there any way to set up different prices for shipping regions for an Australian account.

Something like

```
Domestic (Australia) : $5
North and South America: $15
Europe and Africa: $20
```

Cheers

Cam

Comment: Im aware that i could offer a drop down box with different regions on the button, but it would be very easy for customers to change it to a cheaper one.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal provides a `SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE` key in the array in returns when you use its API. For Great Britain, the code is GB. You can use it to determine your shipping costs:

```
if ($return_data['SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE'] == 'AUS') {
  $shipping_cost = 5;
else if (something...) {
  ...
}
```